# Word 2010 - What is the unknown character displayed as a number?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

In one of our company manuals, someone in our organisation has been doing updates, but something went wrong. After the update, in many many instances of a certain word the initial letter has been replaced with a number. Not always the same number.

Instead of “building”, we had “14uilding” or “17uilding”.

When I started editing these instances I noticed that it wasn’t actually a number, because the number “14” wasn’t build up from two figures, it was actually one symbol. When copying the whole sentence to Notepad, the “14”-symbol was not displayed, i.e. it was replaced by a blank space in Notepad.

I tried to see if it was some kind of Unicode character, but no luck.

I have edited all instances manually now, but I would like to find out if anyone has a hint of what the problem was, so I can solve it next time it occurs…

Comment: You should be able to post the character here. You can't post it in notepad because notepad uses ascii.  Your browser find bar or this website both support unicode characters.   You could search for the character here:  http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html

Comment: Seeing the symbol here would definitely be helpful. There's a decent chance that the mystery updater has a font that you do not. Any chance these mangled words were being given special formatting?

Comment: They could be automatic footnote numbers. You cannot select the digits individually. THey show up with a dotted box around them wheh you click the Show/Hide button. But they would normally be accompanied by some footnotes/endnotes.

IMO the starting point for looking at what is really in your document is to look inside the .docx (which is a ZIP format file with multiple XML and other files) or use Save As to save as the single-file Flat OPC XML format. But that's not particularly easy if you have never done it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hint how you might isolate what characters those are:

Save the Word document to a text file.

Use a hex editor to "view" the odd characters.

Have you ever used a hex editor?  You will see the hex values for the odd characters and then you will need to look these values up in a hex table.